# Could anyone clarify the concept of translational invariance?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

Tonight I stumbled across the concept of translational invariance while studying metric spaces, but I still do not have a clear conception of what it exactly means in abstract terms. Could anyone clarify it to me?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of a "translation" does not make any sense in the context of a general metric space (although the related concept of "isometry" does make sense).

On the other hand, if you were talking about Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$, then a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined to be a translation if there exists $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x)=x+a$.

The phrase "translation invariance" then refers to any property which is invariant under translation. For example, distance is translation invariant, meaning that for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have
$$d(f(x),f(y)) = d(x,y)
$$
Also, angle is translation invariant, meaning that for any oriented segments $\overline{xy}$ and $\overline{xz}$ we have
$$\angle\biggl(\overline{f(x)f(y)} \, , \, \overline{f(x)f(z)}\biggr) = \angle(\overline{xy}, \overline{xz})
$$

Comment: I think the clarification I was looking for is the one expounded by you in the third paragraph. Thank you!